# Too many boot options on grub booloader

Tags: grub-efi

I have a Windows 10 and Ubuntu dual boot on my system and on  grub I am getting some unwanted boot options. I want only my Windows 10 and Ubuntu boot options on my grub and to remove the unwanted EFI boot files.